# Keeping same distance between Text and Icon fonts

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsing tab with Css Icon fonts, i want to keep the same distance between the Title and the Icon font arrow.

Here the example

http://jsfiddle.net/2D3V5/2/

If the Text on the left has the same length, the Icon font arrow keep the same distance and it's ok, but this is not going to happen in my tabs because obviously the texts are gonna be different, so i need to find out how to keep the Arrow Icon at the same distance from the text independently from the length of the text.

Hope the explanation is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just float the arrows right?

Comment: Omg...what a terrible omission, thanks...

Comment: @j08691 But then the arrows aren't at the same distance from the text.

Comment: @Oriol - The OP already has the arrows equidistant from the end of their text. I believe they want the arrows to be aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the images to right. That's a simple way to manage the equal distance. 
Plus, the images of the rest of division are inverted. Do change their classes.

Here is the edited fiddle : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2D3V5/4/)

Comment: But then the arrows aren't at the same distance from the text

Comment: See my fiddle. The arrows are aligned to right and because they are in corner. That makes their distance equal.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/KbdaL.jpg. The arrows have different lengths, so the distance is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/2D3V5/3/

If you want to keep the Arrow Icon at the same distance from the text, but you want the arrows aligned too, you have to place the arrows at the left of your titles.